# How can I know when my code completes all the async work in zone, in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-async

Consider I have code like this:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

foo() {
  print('foo');
}

bar() {
  print('bar');
}

void main() {
  runZoned(() {
    new Timer(const Duration(seconds: 1), foo);
    new Timer(const Duration(seconds: 2), bar);
  });
}
```

How can I know when all the async work inside a Zone is completed? That is, is it possible to know when all the async methods (either via timer, future, etc) that were registered within a zone are complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initially zones did have an "onDone" callback. (See a usage in an old test [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/dart/+/3e89c9e5096d88230e139c7e320466eddf5551ac/dart/tests/lib/async/run_zoned3_test.dart)). However we discovered that it is too hard to keep track of outstanding callbacks. For example: `future.then(callback)` registers a callback, but there is absolutely no guarantee that this callback will ever be invoked.

In fact, it is quite common that futures are never completed. Zones, themselves, contribute to this: when an error originates in a zone that has an error-handler the error will never leave the zone. That means that future-chains outside the zone won't be completed (neither with a value nor the error that got intercepted by the zone).

TL;DR: we had `onDone` on zones but removed it because it was impractical.

Comment: Thanks for the background.

Comment: Looks like Zone.js has a `onZoneLeave` callback: https://github.com/btford/zone.js/

Comment: `onZoneLeave` not just called at the end, when all callbacks are done. It is invoked after every `run` that switches into that zone. If you need that in Dart, just override the `run`s in Dart`s Zones.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find this out too.
It seems the async queue is not implemented in Dart but managed by the VM.
The isolate running the Dart code gets a message to run the registered callbacks.

It might be possible to create a derived Zone that does some bookkeeping about scheduled tasks (add to its own queue before submitting the call to the default implementation and also wrapping the callback to get notified when the callback gets called, to remove it from the queue).

I hope someone comes up with a better answer.

Comment: I think Angular does something like a derived Zone. See https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/70d83c53c350920fc27942a9c3b4c83dff5c10b5/lib/core/zone.dart

Comment: I had found https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/lib/mock/zone.dart#L33. is used in unit tests a lot but as it is in the `mock` library I thought this is just mocking. Your link shows it's more.
It would be great if some of you knowledgabe guys could write an article about Zones. It seems to play an important role in Dart but it's hard to grasp and he code is hard to debug. I encountered many places where it's not possible to set breakpoints. On the other hand it seems not to be too complicated only too abstract to get the intention from code.

Comment: Brian Fords speech is about Zones http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IqtmUscE_U. but it's about JS not Dart.

Comment: I was trying to see how much of Brian's talk is relevant to Dart. It's really good and makes me excited about Zones.  cc @florian-loitsch